# Spark MLlib: Should I call .cache before fitting a model?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Imagine that I am training a Spark MLlib model as follows:

```
val traingData = loadTrainingData(...)
val logisticRegression = new LogisticRegression()

traingData.cache
val logisticRegressionModel = logisticRegression.fit(trainingData)
```

Does the call `traingData.cache` improve performances at training time or is it not needed?

Does the `.fit(...)` method for a ML algorithm call cache/unpersist internally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to call `.cache` for Spark LogisticRegression (and some other models). The `train` method (called by `Predictor.fit(...)`) in [LogisticRegression](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/598446b74b61fee272d3aee3a2e9a3fc90a70d6a/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/LogisticRegression.scala#L486) is implemented as follows:

```
override protected[spark] def train(dataset: Dataset[_]): LogisticRegressionModel = {
  val handlePersistence = dataset.rdd.getStorageLevel == StorageLevel.NONE // true if not cached-persisted
  train(dataset, handlePersistence)
}
```

And later...

```
if (handlePersistence) instances.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

This will generally even be more efficient than a custom call to `.cache` as `instances` in the line above only contains `(label, weight, features)` and not the rest of the data.